# How do I convert Hex values to 32-bit MIPS instructions?

Tags: binary, hex, mips

I need to convert these Hex values to MIPS instructions:

I converted them to binary first, but not sure if it is necessary.

```
Hex: 0x0000 0000 - Binary: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
Hex: 0xAFBF 0000 - Binary: 1010 1111 1011 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000
Hex: 0x3424 001E - Binary: 0011 0100 0010 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Please explain the process so I can do it in the future.

I have this [MIPS reference data sheet](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:q-lunUDHzmYJ:inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf%20mips%20reference%20data%20green%20card&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgid7aJtK2DbfQzzBvq9d_hHI9jhC1imBXZ0YGwJClVHvFDqWoSMsPrXrwzBEzfoY-5k9cdMBKv8BDUGG_AHg5UZBp9TChDJZB-W29mt4lY005DRbJsdPAKwF8GGUpQQ72nX9G9&sig=AHIEtbQA17rihy7IN3Cfx6xxuRODByvzAQ&pli=1)

Comment: Stack Overflow is designed to be used by future people who need help with the same issues you're having, so for future reference please include at least a semi-permanent link with your question, and describe the important contents of the link if possible. Also only include links if they're relevant to the question.

Comment: MIPS reference data sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--CA_Lm6gBWb2N5MUc3SVBvVkE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MIPS instruction encoding is very simple and it was explained in every MIPS documents including the sheet you read above. Just get the opcode field and determine if that's an R, I or J-type instruction to get the remaining parameters correctly. If the opcode is 0 then it's always R type, in that case look up the function field

For the first instruction `0x00000000`:

```
6-bit opcodes = 000000: R type
6-bit funct: 000000 ==> sll
rs, rd, rt = 0
==> sll $0, $0, $0 or nop
```

The second instruction `0xAFBF0000`:

```
opcode: 101011 = 0x2B => sw
```

The last one `0x3424001E`:

```
opcode: 001101 = 0x0D => ori
```

If you use some disassembler like [ODA](http://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) you'll see the result like this

```
.data:0x00000000    00000000    nop   
.data:0x00000004    afbf0000    sw ra,0(sp)   
.data:0x00000008    3424001e    ori a0,at,0x1e
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for a MIPS disassember?  Here's one:

http://acade.au7.de/disasmips.htm